# Does this model work for my relational database?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, authentication, asp.net-identity

Just wondering if this model fits with what I am trying to accomplish:

A user registers and logs in
they search cards and add them to their own collection
they can create multiple new decks, and add cards from their collection into the newly created deck

Another user registers and logs in, 
they can search, create and add cards and decks completely independent of another users cards and decks etc.

Think of gmail, we can all log into the same site, but we can only read emails relative to our accounts.

My models:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public new int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Card> Cards { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Deck> Decks { get; set; }
}

public class Card
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? Atk { get; set; }
    public int? Def { get; set; }
    public string Desc {get; set;}
    public int? Level { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Attribute { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Image")]
    public virtual List<Image> Card_Images { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Deck> Deck { get; set; }


}

public class Deck
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Notes { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Card")]
    public virtual List<Card> Card { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you'd like to post this on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ If a card belongs to deck and deck belongs to user. You don't need list of both in your user model.

Comment: so they user has a collection of cards, which is its own table but can also be added to deck. but yes i'll post this on code review thank you